# mySQL transaction not working properly, instead considers it separately

Tags: mysql, sql

```
START TRANSACTION;
insert into p_table(name, age)
values("anwqe", 23);

insert into p_table(name, age)
values("a12e", 23);

insert into p_table(name, age)
values("12qe", 23);
COMMIT;
```

This is my code and it is not working, I can query one by one however does not consider as one transaction. Furthermore we can have create table inside transaction right?

Comment: Please clarify what "not working" means here. Do you get an error? Do you get unexpected behaviour? Also, you cannot have `create table` (for a non-temporary table) inside a transaction, but this seems like an unrelated/different question. Or do you *have* a `create table` inside your transaction and might it explain your problem?

Comment: Why do this with separate statements? You can have multiple value lists in a single insert: `insert into p_table(name, age)
values("anwqe", 23), ("a12e", 23), ("12qe", 23);`